# core.##### files in Wordpress root folder

Tags: php, wordpress

There are several (4) core.##### (5 numbers, which seem to correspond to the Wordpress version) files, which I've never seen before in the root folder of my Wordpress installation.

They're all 110± MB in size, which makes me think they're just some kind of cached versions of Wordpress core that were downloaded at some point. The thing is that I don't want to leave 4x 110MB files in my root directory - is it safe to delete them?

Comment: Dont know this issue, i would make a backup and try whats happend when u delete the files.

Comment: @mr.void You can safely delete the files, see my answer

Comment: If you have shell access, run `file core.*`; it will tell you what kind of file they are. If they're text files, you could then do `less core.12345` or `head core.12345` to view them. If Lars Beck is right, `file` will report that they are core dumps, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

These are core dumps, you should check your error logs, looks like one ore more server processes frequently crash.

Answer (score 1):

These core.12345 files may contain an image of the current RAM memory of a crashed process.
IMHO, this can happen e.g. if you try to catch an out of memory_limit error within an exception.
I would like to now more about this error too.